# how to show the videos in grid view using video url string

Tags: android, video, android-gridview

I have a URL string in the array. how to display the URL of the video in grid view and on click the grid plays in next screen.
how to implement this? anyone guide me...

I tried for the image it works fine. How to implement for videos, the array is a string...URL...

```
public class act extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
//Integer[] imageIDs={R.drawable.icon,R.drawable.icon,R.drawable.icon};
String uri1="https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/bQaWsVQSLdY/default.jpg";
String uri2="https://i4.ytimg.com/vi/cJQCniWQdno/mqdefault.jpg";
String uri3="https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/D8dA4pE5hEY/mqdefault.jpg";
String[] urls={uri1,uri2,uri3};
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    GridView grd=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    grd.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    grd.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,View v,int pos,long id)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"pic"+(pos+1)+"select ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    });
}
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Context context;
    private int itemBackground;
    ImageAdapter(Context c)
    {
    context=c;
    TypedArray a=obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);
    itemBackground=a.getResourceId(R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground,0);
    a.recycle();
    }
    public int getCount()
    {
        return urls.length;
    }
    public Object getItem(int pos)
    {
        return pos;
    }
    public long getItemId(int pos)
    {
        return pos;
    }
    public View getView(int pos,View cv,ViewGroup vg)
    {
        ImageView imageview=new ImageView(context);
        imageview.setImageResource(urls.length);
        imageview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imageview.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150,120));
        imageview.setBackgroundResource(itemBackground);
        return imageview;
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance...

Comment: video is coming form where ? own server or youtube?

Comment: youtube link stored in server, its coming from server

Comment: then youtube is providing you a thumbnail of that video. why don't you want to show that text?

Comment: no i want to list my database stored videos..after that only i should play in fullscreen...

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19132/java-and-android-era

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are wrong on this stage.

```
How to display the url of video in gridview ?
```

Don't try to print your URL into grid view item. YouTube is provide a thumbnail of specif video in different frame.So directly use that URL and play.

Here is the Image URL for YouTube Thumbnail (order by Frame)

**YouTube URL :** http://img.youtube.com/vi/

**Video_ID :** AxeOPU6n1_M

**Frame Number** : 0.jpg

## Final YouTube Thumbnail URL

http://img.youtube.com/vi/AxeOPU6n1_M/0.jpg

http://img.youtube.com/vi/AxeOPU6n1_M/1.jpg

http://img.youtube.com/vi/AxeOPU6n1_M/2.jpg

So, at the end you have to get `youtube_img_url` from web service so you can use it.

And if you don't know how to set image coming from server then check out below links.

[Example - 1](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/09/23/simplest-lazy-loading-listview-android-data-populated-mysql-database-php/)

[LazyList](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList)

Both example is good now you have to just update your code as per requirement.

```
How to play on click the grid plays in next screen.
```

Here its should be new activity called via intent and this will play in YouTube Player.

```
@Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.videoplaying);
          String url= "Your url";
          Uri uri=Uri.parse(url);
          VideoView video=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoplaying);
          video.setVideoURI(uri);
          video.start();
        }
```

Comment: my link is like this [ https://www.youtube.com/embed/exdhhTjP00g?feature=player_detailpage ]

Comment: i won't print the url i should display the url of video as thumbnail in grid....can you understood..

Comment: i tried for videos thumbnails..its coming but image is not displaying..only background image shows

Answer (score 1):

You try for this:

When selecting one image take that particular url and then start new activity.

New activity code :

```
 @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.videoplaying);
          String url= "Your url";
          Uri uri=Uri.parse(url);
          VideoView video=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoplaying);
          video.setVideoURI(uri);
          video.start();
        }
```

Comment: please read the title first he hasn't ask about how to play. he wants to show that link or  that thumbnail in gird.

Comment: @ chintan khetiya he also asked for playing that video in next screen.This answer is for that..

Comment: Your requirement is: To show thumbnail image of video in grid view .When clicking any thumbnail image that particular video should be shown in another screen..right??

Answer (score -1):

You can refer to this for media playback

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html

Comment: don't want to play in mediaplayer i tried that its not work for youtube link in my case..

Answer (score -1):

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.video);
      String url= "Write your Url";
      Uri uri=Uri.parse(url);
      VideoView video=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoview);
      video.setVideoURI(uri);
      video.start();
    }
```